# How to play embedded flash videos in external players?

Tags: flash, vlc, video-player

As discussed in [a separate question](https://askubuntu.com/q/169292/47206), embedded flash videos are abnormally heavy on GPU resources.

The answer given by [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/169298/47206) (and namely in one comment) shows that

```
”Flash 11+ "attempts" (poorly, it looks like) to use the GPU (hardware) to "decode" the video instead of the CPU (software).
Decoding is a fairly computationally intensive task, but most modern CPUs (except Atoms) will deal with 1080P HD without breaking a sweat.”.
```

So, it seems that a solution would be opening those videos in external players, even without downloading them, so as to put to work the CPU instead of the GPU.

Comment: Heavy CPU usage is not restricted to VIDEO but also applies to STREAMING AUDIO (e.g. RADIO stations) in Firefox or Chromium; streaming in VLC is sooo much more lightweight in comparison!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As this question looks useful to me, I have [created it in order to provide an answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3788/47206). (The meta issue of doing this was discussed and answered ([here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3005/47206) and [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/111/ought-one-to-answer-ones-own-question)).

---

A specialized application to see Youtube videos in an external player is **Youtube Viewer** (`youtube-viewer`). It runs in terminal and uses `mplayer` or `mpv` to play the youtube video.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-viewer
```

More [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/youtube-viewer-complete-youtube-client.html).

By default it uses `mplayer`. To make it use `mpv` instead, run `youtube-viewer --video-player=mpv`. So, a desktop file with this content may be useful:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=bash -c 'youtube-viewer --video-player=mpv'
Icon=youtube-viewer
Name[en_US]=Youtube Viewer
Name=Youtube Viewer
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

When running the program, a terminal window opens, saying:

```
=>> Search for YouTube videos (:h for help)
> ^J>
```

Just type the search item. Then type the corresponding number(s) of the videos you want to be played.

[image]

---

A cross-platform solution that is not limited to youtube is to use the well-known Firefox addon [FlashGot](http://flashgot.net/), which is meant to send video streams to different download managers, but make it to send the URL stream to VLC (or `mpv`, which I prefer lately):

- add VLC to Flashgot list: FlashGot options, General tab, Add, give a name 'VLC' , - then go to the VLC executable and select it

[image]
[image]

- FlashGot options, FlashGot tab, choose VLC

[image]

- playing the video in Firefox, a Flashgot button should appear (add that to the toolbar or the status bar). Right-click the button, Available formats, and left-click the video. VLC should start playing the video stream

[image]

---

**SMPlayer.** - limited to youtube (unless used with the solution above: have not tested that yet)

[image: Install via the software center]

**and the Youtube Browser**

[image: Install via the software center]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install smplayer smtube
```

[image]

It starts the separate application, SMPlayer Youtube Browser, to search for videos. One can create a link/desktop launcher to it, 
[image]

or just run

> smtube

**Using VLC**. It looks like VLC is able to start videos of this kind from more websites, while **smplayer is limited to youtube**.

[image: Install via the software center]

One can add the link to the video in VLC 
[image]

**Using Totem:**

[image: Install via the software center]

Some [plugins](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/totem-plugins/) are available for Totem player, among which a youtube browser similar to that of SMPlayer. You can open youtube videos in Totem, at lower quality it seems than in the previous options, but they load faster and are perfect for listening music from youtube.

[image]

There is also an [arte-tv plugin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/totem-plugin-arte/) for Totem that is not working at the moment... but maybe it will in the future... and [supplementary plugins](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/totem-plugins-extra/), including a BBC iPlayer. (The later no better than the one for arte-tv I fear.)

But I think that **a more elegant method** is **using add-ons/extensions to open the external players directly from the internet browser's interface or context menu**, like the aforementioned Flashgot addon.

The re is also the **[Firefox Openwith addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/)**, created initially to open links in different web browsers, can do just that, by adding in its Preferences `vlc` and `smtube`  instead of/beside browsers .

[image]
[image]

In Chromium there is an extension to start youtubes in VLC - [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jldiailifbdkepgpcojllmkbakleicab?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

To use it, the youtube video has to be playing, the VLC web interface has to be enabled  (VLC Tools-Preferences-Show Settings -All-Interface-Main-enable Web, restart VLC) and VLC has to be already open.
[image]

[image]

While VLC seems able to do this outside youtube, it has limitations when dealing with other websites. In Dailymotion works perfectly, but on Google videos it already may have problems, in others it's the OpenWith addon that would not work. I hadn't time to test them enough, I'll update this post in time, and invite comments and edits that would help find ways to open any embedded flash in VLC or other external player.

(This answer was based on ideas coming from [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx), [Halknner](https://askubuntu.com/users/64720/halkinn) and [user55822](https://askubuntu.com/users/55822/user55822) as they answered or commented on [other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/169292/47206).)

---

There is **a VLC add-on to play YouTube videos and playlists** - [here](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/+Youtube+playlist?content=149909)

Copy the URL of the youtube video or playlist (must contain "list=PL...")
Start VLC, press Ctrl+N, paste the url then click on "Play" (or Alt+P then Enter), the video /playlist should start.

[image]

In 'Media', 'Save Playlist to File' and may open it later in VLC.

Comment: @KirillGolikov - an answer specifically on a cross-platform solution: http://superuser.com/a/819188/162573

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a pretty cool way to view all flash videos outside of your browser. But at the moment I only know it works on chrome and chromium. Before the page with the flash player loads press    ctrl+shift+J   This will open a tab at the bottom of the screen, it will have different tabbed options, one of them is NETWORK. You go into that one and open the flash video when it loads the link to the video will appear there all you have to do is copy it either to VLC or totem both of them play streams.

I'm a huge VLC fan, but I gotta give it to TOTEm in this one it loads the videos a la flash if you leave it paused it will download the video VLC will not.

Comment: in what way is this different from my answer on vlc and totem?

Answer (score 0):

Since some years, I'm usually grabbing flash files directly from the `/proc` directory, when they are here, in order to play them with VLC, which is by far the best tool around to watch videos.

It's not working with youtube, but it works great with most of the other Streaming website. I finally decided to make it more usable by writing some proper function to use within your shell.

Feel free to try it, it works great:

```
$ curl -SsL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beaudev/view-da-flash/master/view_da_flash.sh>source

$ view_daflash
```

Source : https://github.com/beaudev/view-da-flash